Lines in median image created from Seninel-1 image
I am trying to create the median image of the coastal regions of Bangladesh. The imagecollection has around 319 images. When creating the median image, I get some lines as shown in the image below

I think this is because multiple image strips are used in the median and are of multiple orientations/ incidence angles. I tried using a trial-and-error approach using the angle band, but it didn't work out. Is there any solution?
/******************************************
 *************** AREA OF STUDY ************
 ******************************************/


var roi = 
    /* color: #ffc82d */
    /* displayProperties: [
      {
        "type": "rectangle"
      }
    ] */
    ee.Geometry.Polygon(
        [[[88.9659628796457, 23.833598504098383],
          [88.9659628796457, 21.168219371114713],
          [92.1574911999582, 21.168219371114713],
          [92.1574911999582, 23.833598504098383]]], null, false);
            
var month = 5
var year1 = 2014
var year2 = 2024
    

Map.centerObject(roi, 10);
Map.setOptions('HYBRID');

var band = 'VV';

/*******************************************
 ************* VIS PARAMS ******************
 *******************************************/
var imageVisParam_Median = {"opacity":1,"bands":[band],"min":-20.46595116382209,"max":-4.361765242123628,"gamma":1};

var maskBorder = function (image) {
  var minAngle = 20.88
  var maxAngle = 55.35
  var angle = image.select('angle')
  var sideMask = angle.gt(minAngle).and(angle.lt(maxAngle))
  return image.updateMask(sideMask)
}

/**********************************************
 ********** FILTERING THE COLLECTION **********
 **********************************************/

var collection = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S1_GRD')
    .filter(ee.Filter.listContains('transmitterReceiverPolarisation', band))
    .filter(ee.Filter.eq('instrumentMode', 'IW'))
    .filter(ee.Filter.or(ee.Filter.eq('orbitProperties_pass', 'ASCENDING'), ee.Filter.eq('orbitProperties_pass', 'DESCENDING')))
    .filter(ee.Filter.inList('orbitProperties_pass', ['ASCENDING', 'DESCENDING']))
    .filterBounds(roi)
    .sort('GRD_Post_Processing_start', false);
    
//print('COL', collection.select('angle'))


/***********************************************
 * COMBINING THEM INTO ONE LIST FOR EACH MONTH *
 ***********************************************/
 
var all_img = collection
  .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(month, month, 'month'))
  .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(year1, year2, 'year'))
  .map(maskBorder)
  .select(band);


/*****************************************************
 * FOR VIEWING THE NO. OF ELEMENTS IN EACH COLLECTION *
 *****************************************************/
print('IMAGES:', all_img);


/*****************************************
 * CALCULATING THE MEDIAN FOR EACH MONTH *
 *****************************************/
var median_img = all_img.median().clip(roi);
print('Median_img', median_img)

var projection = median_img.projection().getInfo()
print(projection.crs)

/*****************************************
 ********* DISPLAYING THE MEDIAN *********
 *****************************************/
 
Map.addLayer(median_img, {min: -25, max: 0}, 'median_img', 1);

Export.image.toAsset({
  image: median_img,
  description: 'Median_image_coastal_bd_may',
  assetId: 'Coastal_Median_May_only',
  crs: projection.crs,
  //crsTransform: projection_map.transform,
  scale: 10,
  region: roi,
  maxPixels: 1e13,
})


Here's the code: https://code.earthengine.google.com/51baa1a767e33f71902af2694e86c2b1?noload=true

You might want to process your images to gamma0:
var collection = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S1_GRD')
    ...
    .map(toGamma0)

function toGamma0(image) {
  var gamma0 = image.expression('i/(cos(angle * pi / 180))', {
    'i': image.select(image.bandNames().remove('angle')),
    'angle': image.select('angle'),
    'pi': Math.PI
  })
  return gamma0
    .addBands(image.select('angle'))
    .copyProperties(image, image.propertyNames())
}

https://code.earthengine.google.com/d82bc7eb0bcd5af4502d084e44821b6a?noload=true

could you explain what this code is doing cause the images being stitched together to cover the whole area for creating the median is still quite visible.
